# How to make QTreeWidget call sizeHint when resized?

Tags: qt, delegates, qt5, qtreewidget

I am using a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` in order to display data in a `QTreeWidget`. Thus I have implemented the `paint()` and the `sizeHint()` functions.

The painting works fine, but I have some issues with the `sizeHint`. The problem is that I am displaying some text that will wrap if the horizontal space is insufficient for displaying without wrapping. The issue is that Qt does not seem to call the `sizeHint` function when the `QTreeWidget` is being resized. Only the `paint` function gets called in these cases but as my items change their row height (depending on if and how often they wrap lines) this causes the layout of the tree to get messed up.

The situation currently is: The layout works as expected right after the widget's creation and as long as it does not get resized, everything works like charm. If however one is to resize the widget, the text starts or stops wrapping,changing the item's height (this is all done in the `paint` function that still gets called regularly) and then the vertical layout of the tree is destroyed (either the items are spaced out with huge distances or they start overlapping, depending on whether the items are now taking less or more vertical space to render).

I have tried explicitly setting `uniformHeights` to `false` and `wordWrap` to `true` on the tree widget, but this did not seem to have any effect.

This is an exemplary `sizeHint` function:

```
QSize MyItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &inOption, const QModelIndex &index) {
    QStyleOptionView option = inOption;
    initStyleOption(option);

    QTextDocumentOptioon opt;
    opt.setWrapMode(Qt::WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere);
    opt.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft)

    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setDefaultTextOption(opt);
    doc.setTextWidth(option.widget->size().width());
    doc.setHtml("An example text that may or may not wrap");

    return doc.size();
}
```

How do I get the tree widget to call the item delegate's `sizeHint` function to be called more frequently (on all resize events)?

Comment: on all resize events

Comment: To make it less enigmatic: reimplement `ResizeEvent` and call `repaint` manually.

Comment: @scopchanov does `repaint` also re-compute the layout? From the name it seems that it would only repaint the existing buttons...

Comment: One way to know this is to try it.

Comment: I just tested this out and it seems to be as I said: `repaint` (and `update` for that matter) only cause a repaint but not a re-computation of the item's sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is partly inspired by the comments from [scopchanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5366641/scopchanov) - thanks for that!

In order to get the tree widget to update its layout, I had to first of all subclass `QTreeWidget` and then override `QTreeWidget::resizeEvent`. This way I get a hook into which I can inject code every time the widget is being resized.

In order to get the widget to actually update its layout, I use `QAbstractItemView::scheduleDelayedItemsLayout` (`QAbstracTItemView::executeDelayedItemsLayout` should work as well).

Thus all in all my `resizeEvent` function looks like this:

```
void MyCustomTree::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    scheduleDelayedItemsLayout();

    QTreeWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Refs:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#executeDelayedItemsLayout
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scheduleDelayedItemsLayout

Comment: So, basically I was right saying, that you have the key to the solution, i.e. _on all resize events_, at the end of your question. ;) Glad it worked!

Comment: @scopchanov yes indeed. Thanks again! :)